# How to encrypt data before inserting it in a bytea column

Tags: elixir, ecto, pgcrypto

I'm trying to find a way to directly insert data through a `bytea` column directly. How should I do it?

In our tables, we have several columns which need to be encrypted. We are currently using the `PGCRYPTO` module provided in PostgreSQL. However, we are having trouble encrypting the data before inserting it to the `bytea` column.

The method we currently use is inserting our non-encrypted data to the column before fetching it again and then encrypting it using `fragment('PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT('data', 'AES_KEY')')` before updating the column.

Is there is a way of encrypting a file before inserting it without using the method above? I tried using the `excrypto` module, but it produces results in a different format than `pgcrypto`, causing an error.

Thank you in advance.